# Creating a function in excel VBA to calculate the average point in a circular set of numbers

Tags: excel, vba, average, custom-function

Still fairly amateur at this so please be gentle. I am trying to create a function that gives the average of a set of numbers. The set of numbers are actually the teeth of a cog. The primary tooth is always tooth 1 (identifiable as painted), damage or stoppage is recorded on teeth in a clockwise rotation so damage at teeth 7 and 23 would be at 7 and 23 teeth from the starting tooth. Now an anomaly occurs when you calculate a normal average as the average of stoppages at teeth 3, 4 and 33 would infact be 1 NOT 14.33 as per a standard average. I have calculated that to find the average, and by average I mean more nearer the median of a set of circular numbers. I add one to each value in the range and calculate the difference between the maximum and minimum numbers using the MOD function. Once I identify the first position of the shortest difference it is simply a case of subtracting the incremented value from the new average. It probably is better described in a table...

[image]

As you can see, the real average or median is tooth 1, which is the average minus the increment of the first number set with the smallest difference.
The code I have at present to go through an do these calculations is giving a value# error but my experience with custom functions is very minimal and I don't know where to start in correcting the issue, pointers would be appreciated, a solution would be fantastic. Many thanks in advance.

```
Public Function AVGDISTCALC(rng As Range)
'Determines the average distance of a number of distances on a 37 tooth wheel.
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim avg As Integer
Dim diff As Integer
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Write the range to an array.
    Arr = rng
    'Cycle through each increment on the 37 tooth wheel.
    diff = 38
    For i = 1 To 37
    Arr = rng
        'For each increment calculate the min and max of the range.
        For r = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
                If (Arr(r, c) + i) Mod 37 = 0 Then
                    Arr(r, c) = 37
                Else
                    Arr(r, c) = (Arr(r, c) + i) Mod 37
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
        If WorksheetFunction.Max(Arr) - WorksheetFunction.Min(Arr) < diff Then
            diff = WorksheetFunction.Max(Arr) - WorksheetFunction.Min(Arr)
            avg = WorksheetFunction.Average(Arr)
            x = i
        End If
    Next i
    
    AVGDISTCALC = avg - x
    
End Function
```

Comment: `cell.Value = 37`... you can't modify a cell's value if you're calling this as a user-defined function in a cell.

Comment: Thanks BigBen that makes kinda sense, are you suggesting I should be placing the calculated value sets into an array? If so how do I know it's size as the range of numbers can vary? I'm presuming its some use of Lbound and Ubound, which I will have to read up on further to understand.

Comment: As long as `rng` is comprised of multiple cells, `rng.Value` is a 2D array. [Here's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) some more reading on arrays and ranges.

Comment: That looks a brilliant resource thanks BigBen, it looks well explained. I will have to go away and read it a few times with some experimenting to understand fully though as I'm a "play with it a few times" type of learner. Thank you.

Comment: BigBen, I've gone through that resource you linked and it is amazingly simple how it explains the array subject, must be because I understood it! I've now amended my code to place the values into an array and perform the calculations but I'm thinking the result is wrong, my result is 4, for the example it should be 1. I think the problem is I'm adding the next increment to an array value that has already been incremented but I'm not sure how I would code wanting to use the initial value only. Other than writing the code that is above the same number of times that I have teeth on the cog. Help!

Comment: It may take me some time to replicate the setup... One option is to debug this from within the VBEditor by calling the function in a new subroutine, and then stepping through with F8 and using the watch window to see what the code is doing.

Comment: I did that BigBen so I knew I wouldn't waste anyone's time, on the second running of i where the value is two it adds the two to the first value in the array which is now 4. That first value should of been 3, its the first value in the range. I don't want the array value to be updated - I hope I'm making sense, apologies.

Comment: Eureka! I got the solution BigBen!!! I just needed to add the range back to the array at the start of each iteration of i. In essence formatting it each time ready to perform the new calculation. Thanks for the steer on to the use of the array and the resource. :-)

Comment: Although I am happy with the function I created, it has a limitation, it only calculates for a continuous range, it doesn't accept a non-contiguous range or an offset function as a range. Is there something I can change in the top instructions to rectify this? I tried changing rng as a variant not a range but that shot in the dark didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a non-contiguous range, you can't read its `.Value` into an array in one line. You have to loop.

Comment: Thanks BigBen, I was thinking more of using it in the worksheet though, if I am calculating an offset range it gives a #value error, it just means I need to know every range I'm averaging, bit of a pain but I can live with. I searched a little and started following the route of a parramarray in the function parenthesis  but this seemed quite above my head how it was explained, that's not a solution is it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your goal is so I can't opine as to whether `ParamArray` is a solution or not.

Comment: I just wanted it to be as flexible as the general AVERAGE function in excel really, you can use non continuous ranges and continuous in that, you can also get the AVERAGE of a dynamic range. Mine has to ("RC:RC") which is a bit limiting. Thanks for all you've done though so far, I was just looking for a yes or no as to whether a ParanArray argument was a solution and if so I'd research it. I didn't want to chase down a dead end thats all. Thanks again BB.

Comment: It very well might be a solution, if you need to pass multiple ranges as arguments. Sounds worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to BigBen for the steer onto using an array. To calculate the average of a circular set of numbers I used the code below. I hope this example helps anyone else with similar issues. If you need a different number of cog teeth you should just change the MOD value appropriately.

```
Public Function AVGDISTCALC(rng As Range)
'Determines the average distance of a number of distances on a 37 tooth wheel.
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim avg As Integer
Dim diff As Integer
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Write the range to an array.
    Arr = rng
    'Cycle through each increment on the 37 tooth wheel.
    diff = 38
    For i = 1 To 37
    Arr = rng
        'For each increment calculate the min and max of the range.
        For r = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
                If (Arr(r, c) + i) Mod 37 = 0 Then
                    Arr(r, c) = 37
                Else
                    Arr(r, c) = (Arr(r, c) + i) Mod 37
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
        If WorksheetFunction.Max(Arr) - WorksheetFunction.Min(Arr) < diff Then
            diff = WorksheetFunction.Max(Arr) - WorksheetFunction.Min(Arr)
            avg = WorksheetFunction.Average(Arr)
            x = i
        End If
    Next i
    
    Select Case avg - x
    Case 0
        AVGDISTCALC = 37
    Case Is > 0
        AVGDISTCALC = avg - x
    Case Is < 0
        AVGDISTCALC = (avg - x) + 37
    End Select
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Seems to return the same value as your example, but would be4 useful to have more sample calculations to test...

```
Function AvgDistance(vals As Range, teeth) As Double
    Dim arr, i As Long, tot As Long, v
    arr = vals.Value
    tot = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        v = arr(i, 1)
        tot = tot + IIf(v > (teeth / 2), v - teeth, v)
    Next i
    AvgDistance = tot / UBound(arr, 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the time spent on it Tim but the first answer delivered. I did try the function but it wasn't coming out with the same answers as mine. Thank you again though. :-)